# Group by date and then by city on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activerecord

I have an api that its output must look like:

```
[
  {
    "store": "store",
    "date": "2020/05/03",
    "address": {
       "city": "city1"
       "address_line_1": "address"
     },
    "sales_count": 10,
  },
  {
    "store": "store",
    "date": "2020/05/03",
    "address": {
       "city": "city2"
       "address_line_1": "address"
     },
    "sales_count": 21,
  },
]
```

I know how to handle the grouping and the sales count, but I'm having issues with grouping by city

Store.first.sales.group(:date).count would be the sales_count but I'm not sure how to include the group by address.

Taking into account that address = Store.first.sales.first.address

This means that a store has many sales and each sale has an address.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not only just want to count sales but also return data, then you should prefer `PARTITION BY` to `GROUP BY`.
You can `PARTITION BY` combine date, address:

```sql
SELECT store, date, address, 
COUNT(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY date, address) AS sales_count
FROM _
```

Beside that, if you do nothing with data but return them, then the best practice is just call sql directly from adapter (so we avoid the creation of ActiveRecord model objects was causing all sorts of memory contention problem)

```rb
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
 "SELECT store, date, address, 
  COUNT(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY date, address) AS sales_count 
  FROM _"
)
result.each do |msg|
 # json serialize ???
end
```